# List comprehention with 2 variable

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Is there any way to use list comprehension in this case ?

```
l=[]
for i in range(-1,2):
    for j in range(-1,2):
        l.append([i,j])
```

Output:

```
[[-1, -1], [-1, 0], [-1, 1], [0, -1], [0, 0], [0, 1], [1, -1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
l = [[i, j] for i in range(-1, 2) for j in range(-1, 2)]
```

Result:

```
# print(l)
[[-1, -1], [-1, 0], [-1, 1], [0, -1], [0, 0], [0, 1], [1, -1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
```